# Emmet autocomplete is not working for php files in Sublime (Expand abbreviations)

Tags: php, sublimetext3, emmet

I am using Emmet plugin for HTML files in Sublime. But when I want to type HTML codes in a PHP file like views files in Laravel then Emmet is not expanding abbreviations.

For example: when I type `html:5` and press tab in an HTML file in Sublime then Emmet autocomplete will convert it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

But when I do the same in a file with .php extension and press tab nothing will happen. Is it a sublime configuration problem or is there any solution for fast typing HTML codes with Emmet in Sublime for PHP files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README in Emmet's [Package Control page](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) explain clearly how to do this - scroll down to the `How to expand abbreviations with Tab in other syntaxes` section:

> Emmet expands abbreviations in limited syntaxes only: HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS, Stylus and PostCSS. The reason to restrict Tab handler to a limited syntax list is because it breaks native Sublime Text snippets.
>
> If you want to abbreviation with Tab in other syntaxes (for example, JSX, HAML etc.) you have to tweak your keyboard shorcuts settings: add `expand_abbreviation_by_tab` command for tab key for required syntax scope selectors. To get current syntax scope selector, press ⇧⌃P (OSX) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, it will be displayed in editor status bar.
>
> Go to `Preferences > Key Bindings — User` and insert the following JSON snippet with properly configured scope selector instead of `SCOPE_SELECTOR` token:

```js
{
  "keys": ["tab"], 
  "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", 

  // put comma-separated syntax selectors for which 
  // you want to expandEmmet abbreviations into "operand" key 
  // instead of SCOPE_SELECTOR.
  // Examples: source.js, text.html - source
  "context": [
    {
      "operand": "SCOPE_SELECTOR", 
      "operator": "equal", 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "selector"
    }, 

    // run only if there's no selected text
    {
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "selection_empty"
    },

    // don't work if there are active tabstops
    {
      "operator": "equal", 
      "operand": false, 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "has_next_field"
    }, 

    // don't work if completion popup is visible and you
    // want to insert completion with Tab. If you want to
    // expand Emmet with Tab even if popup is visible -- 
    // remove this section
    {
      "operand": false, 
      "operator": "equal", 
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "auto_complete_visible"
    }, 
    {
      "match_all": true, 
      "key": "is_abbreviation"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `SCOPE_SELECTOR` value for PHP is `embedding.php text.html.basic`.